# C++: Are there any guarantees about the binary representation of boolean?

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash

I am working on a [new hashing system](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3980.html). Part of the implementation requires passing a pointer to some memory location into an algorithm functor with a signature like this:

```
void
operator()(void const* key, std::size_t len) noexcept
{
    unsigned char const* p = static_cast<unsigned char const*>(key);
    unsigned char const* const e = p + len;
    std::size_t h = 14695981039346656037u;
    for (; p < e; ++p)
        h = (h ^ *p) * 1099511628211u;
    return h;
}
```

When operating on fundamental types, I just pass in a pointer to the start of the type and the size:

```
template <class HASHALG>
void hash_append(HASHALG& hashAlg, char const input)
{
    hashAlg(&input, sizeof(input));
}
```

The reason I ask if there any guarantees about the binary representation of boolean, is because I want to know if the following will behave as expected:

```
template <class HASHALG>
void hash_append(HASHALG& hashAlg, bool const input)
{
    hashAlg(&input, sizeof(input));
}
```

What I am afraid might happen is that compilers may choose that a true bool can have any non-zero integral representation. i.e.:

```
10110010 => true
10101010 => true
10100010 => true
00100010 => true
01100110 => true
00000000 => false
```

If this is the case, then hashing as bytes is not valid, because the same value(`true`) can produce many different hashes.

I have searched the standard, and all I can find is the following two sections:

> (3.9.1.7) Types bool, char, char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called integral types. A synonym for integral type is integer type. The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system.
>
> (4.5.6) A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type int, with false becoming zero and true becoming one.

So I know that an int will have an integral representation, and I know that when converted to an int, it will be either 1 or 0, but does the standard guarantee that it will have a fixed representation? It seems like in most cases compilers would just implement this:

```
true => 00000001
false => 00000000
```

If there is no guarantee that this will be the representation, I don't want to get burned by some obscure edge case.

Comment: `[expr.sizeof] Note: in particular, sizeof(bool), sizeof(char16_t), sizeof(char32_t), and sizeof(wchar_t) are implementation-defined.`

Comment: @user657267: Thanks, however, implementation defined size is not an issue. Hashes are allowed to be different across machines, so hashing more or fewer bytes is ok as long as its *consistent*. I'm more concerned about whether the representation of `true` in those 1, 2, 527, whatever, number of bytes is always the same or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All types but `char` can have padding bits (aka non-value bits).
`struct`s often even have whole padding bytes.
Also, some types have multiple representations of the same value, and some have trap representations.

For most floating point, there are numerous NaN's and two zeroes.
In a segmented architecture, pointers with ddifferent representations might compare equal.

Most implementations restrict `bool` to one representation for each value, which has advantages and downsides. (Ever seen `a` and `!a` both being false / true?)

So, your hashing method might not be appropriate...
Perhaps do a pre-transformation for the affected primitive types?
And explicitly pass all members for the `struct`?

Comment: +1 for the padding bits & bytes. The "bool representation" stuff is somewhat misleading. The representation has nothing to do with `operator!`. An implementation may assign bit pattern `1001` to `true` and `101010` to false, as long as all the conversions and operators work as defined in the Standard. E.g., `bool(0)` must be `false`.

Comment: @MSalters: I some months ago read a blog article where in the end, it boiled down to  a `bool` storing neither the representation for `true` nor `false`. Thus, neither test passed. Should I have explicitly named the C++ / C convention of not-0 is `true` there?

Comment: That is not possible in portable C++. Of course, after Undefined Behavior **anything** can be true, including an `int` having a value of 3.5 (no kidding, Crays could do that).

Answer (score 0):

There are no guarantees. You don't show where the void pointer key is used, but I have a feeling you will use a cast which has undefined behavior.

Comment: I have updated it to include an example function body. I was under the impression that it was kosher to cast `const void *` to `const char *`. That is how many hashing algorithms access memory.

Comment: @GBleaney If the original pointer stored in key was not `unsigned char *`, then the cast is undefined behavior. It's ok to create a compiler-specific library, but be aware you are doing that. You use a template for hashAlg but a void pointer for key. Why not use a template for key as well?

Comment: A template parameter wouldn't really make a difference there, because either way, we need to convert to char to be able to do hashing operations on generic bytes of data

Comment: @NeilKirk: the standard makes a specific exception to the strict aliasing rule for `char *`, both signed and unsigned. Thus, there's no UB in casting any pointer to `unsigned char *` and reading from it (although what you find in there is implementation-specific).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thanks for the clarification. The key thing though is it's still not universally guaranteed what you will find there.

Comment: @GBleaney You can use bitwise operations to transform the key into bytes of data.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that `hash(x)==hash(y)` should hold for any `x==y`, regardless of type. I would expect the problem to be bigger for floats, as +0.0 and -0.0 are equal but have different representations.

For `bool` at least you can fix the representation problem by specializing `hashAlg<bool>(bool b)` to just return `int(b)`. In fact, you probably want to do the same for all small types (so also char and short). Hashing them using the formula given can only produce unintended collisions.